# POST request with digest auth in R

Tags: r

I have some url, some raw data that looks like json and auth creds.
Everything together works great via postman, but now i need to automate it in R.

For example:

```
url1 = 'https://site.io/v2/passes/?values=true'
bod = paste0('{"values": [{"value": "0","label": "label1"},{"value": "5","label": "label2"}] }')
```

I've already tried this one

```
r <- POST(url1, body = bod, encode = "raw", httr::add_headers(.headers=headers)
          , httr::authenticate("user", "password", type="digest"))
```

But it seems incorrect (and also getting 400 error)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `bod` is a text string. When you use `encode="raw"`, you have to also specify the Content-encoding header if the host is expecting one (and in this case, I assume it's expecting "application/json":

```
headers <- c(headers, `Content-encoding`="application/json")
POST(url1, body=bod, encode="raw", add_headers(.headers=headers), ...)
```

Comment: Thank you, but same result(